# Stop Parameter Prompt When Opening a Report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm writing VBA code to change the record source of a report in Access. However, most of the sources I'll be changing it to will leave a few columns without a control source, so it keeps prompting me to enter parameters for those fields. Is it possible to use `textBoxName.ControlSource = "nameofsource"`, `textBoxName.Value = "0"`, or potentially something else, to get around this?

I've tried using the above statements, but they either don't do what I'm looking for, or I'm doing something wrong. I set one textbox's control source to something successfully, but it still asked me for a parameter and displayed that input even though in properties it showed the source I set as its control source.

Here's the piece of code I've been messing with

```
Select Case RAMsize

Case Is = 7

     DoCmd.OpenReport "rRAM10x10", acViewReport

     Reports!rRAM10x10.RecordSource = "tRAM7x7"

     Reports!rRAM10x10!tBox8.ControlSource = "blank"
```

Any assistance is always appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure out how to get the `.ControlSource` statements to work by adding `OpenArgs` to the `DoCmd.Open` statement, and using that string as a condition for an `If` statement.

```
Select Case RAMsize

Case Is = 7

DoCmd.OpenReport "rRAM10x10", acViewReport, , , , "Dim7"

If Reports!rRAM10x10.OpenArgs = "Dim7" Then


    Reports!rRAM10x10!tBox8.ControlSource = "blank"
    Reports!rRAM10x10!tBox9.ControlSource = "blank"
    Reports!rRAM10x10!tBox10.ControlSource = "blank"


End If

'Changes the report properties to read the appropriate table for a 7x7 RAM
Reports!rRAM10x10.RecordSource = "tRAM7x7"
```

This successfully got rid of the parameter prompts

Answer (score 0):

It might be in reverse order:

```
 Reports!rRAM10x10!tBox8.ControlSource = ""
 Reports!rRAM10x10.RecordSource = "tRAM7x7"
```

Comment: I actually figured it out myself around the time you posted that answer, but I appreciate the response non-the-less!